# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host [LOCAL]

Tags: android, windows, url, android-virtual-device

I use the `INTERNET` uses-permission in the manifest file.

If I type `URL url = new URL('http://www.example.com/page')` (remote server) it will work.
But if I type `URL url = new URL('http://example.local/page')` (local server) it will return the error

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "example.local": No address associated with hostname
```

Now in `%WINDIR%/System32/drivers/etc/hosts` I wrote this entry :

```
10.101.0.179  example.local
```

I can't use `new URL('http://10.101.0.179/page')` because example.local is a virtualHost in my apache configuration.

Can't my AVD looks into the *hosts* file ? what should I do to tell android to fetch the ip `10.101.0.179` but still send a proper information to apache and tell it to serve the virtual host `example.local` ?

Comment: "Can't my AVD looks into the hosts file ? " -- no. AFAIK, `.local` names are used with mDNS. I don't know if Android uses mDNS to resolve names, and I don't know if your server environment are set up to announce `example.local` via mDNS. Can other machines on your network see your machine via `example.local`?

Comment: @CommonsWare no, via example.local they don't, i had to edit `hosts` manually on my main computer. Can't I use the `HttpUrlConnection` object to add the host name in the header of the http request ?

Comment: That's a possibility, though I have never tried that. AFAIK, to do that would use `setRequestProperty()`, probably with `Host` as the property name and `example.local` as the value. The URL then would use the actual IP address.

Comment: @CommonsWare how sweet, that did the trick. Thanks

Comment: If you get a chance, post answer with the code that you wound up using.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to request a web-page from your local HTTP server and the page is bounded to a *virtualHost*, so let say you need to reach `http://example.local/mypage` and if as pointed by @CommonsWare you don't use mDNS to resolve inter-local domain-names, android will probably throw the same error message as it reads in the title of this question. Here's the solution I am using :

let's say `http://example.local/mypage` refers to the ip address `10.101.0.179`, Android won't be able to resolve `example.local`, you need to write the raw url (of your actual local server)

```
try {
  ...
  URL url = new URL("http://10.101.0.179/mypage");
  HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpUrlConnection) url.openConnection();
  ...
}
...
```

But now when Apache receives this request, unless serving your desired host, `10.101.0.179` won't be understood in case of a *VirtualHost*. To round-about this problem, just modify the `Host` http-header property using `setRequestProperty` :

```
...
conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "example.local");
...
```

And it should work.

Answer (score -1):

First you must check if you have given INTERNET permission in your manifest file or not, second you make sure that your emulator or computer has a valid internet. If it doesn't work than you can do following:

If you are using localhost url than you must convert that url into IP address to work with App specially using Android emulator.

For example :

My Current url is

`http://mylocaladdress:9090/myapp.svc/ForgetPassword?EmailID=test@test.com`

Now you can put the following command into terminal on mac or you can use cmd on windows

```
ping mylocaladdress
```

The result will give u the IP address and my final url becomes

```
http://10.1.2.111:9090/myapp.svc/ForgetPassword?EmailID=test@test.com
```

This url worked perfectly in android emulator without exception.